# Probability of making it across a path of $n$ tiles through random walk

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, combinatorics, systems-of-equations, random-walk

### The problem

Imagine someone moving across a path laid out on a 2D grid:

[image]

The white tiles are the path; the surrounding red tiles are, say, deadly lava. They repeatedly move randomly **north**, **east**, **south**, or **west**, with equal probability, and have to make it from the *Start* tile to the *End* tile without stepping onto the lava.

What is the probability $p(n)$ that they succeed on an $n$-square-long path ($n=5$ is shown above)?

---

### What I’ve tried

Number the tiles $1, \dots, n$, so that we’re walking from $1$ to $n$.

Call $a_k$ the probability we succeed when starting at the $k$-th tile. Clearly, $a_n = 1$, and we’re interested in the value of $a_1$.

From the $k$-the tile, there’s a 25% chance we move back to tile $k-1$, a 25% chance we move forward to tile $k+1$, and a 50% chance we step north or south onto a red tile and lose. So $a_k = \frac 14 \left( a_{k-1} + a_{k+1} \right)$, where $a_0 = 0$.

Putting the equations for $a_1, \dots, a_{n}$ in a matrix system gets us:

\begin{equation}
\newcommand{\mof}{-1/4}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \mof & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\mof & 1 & \mof & \dots & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \mof & 1 & \dots & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 1 & \mof & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & \mof & 1 & \mof \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & \color{red}0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1 \\ a_2 \\ a_3 \\ \vdots \\ a_{n-2} \\ a_{n-1} \\ a_n
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{1}
\end{equation}

I wrote some Mathematica code to solve this system for a given $n$ and give the value of $a_1$:

```
p[n_] :=
  LinearSolve[
    Table[If[x == y, 1,
            If[y == n, If[x == n,1,0],
              If[Abs[x - y] == 1, -1/4, 0]]],
          {y, 1, n}, {x, 1, n}],
    Table[If[x == n, 1, 0], {x, 1, n}]
  ][[1]]
```

The first few values $p(1), p(2), \dots$ are
$$
\frac11, \frac1{4}, \frac1{15}, \frac1{56}, \frac1{209}, \frac1{780}, \dots,
$$
the inverses of [A001353](https://oeis.org/A001353) in the OEIS, which suggests a closed form:

$$p(n) = \frac{2 \sqrt{3}}{\left( 2 + \sqrt{3} \right)^n - \left( 2 - \sqrt{3} \right)^n}$$

But I’m not sure how to get there. I doubt there’s a nice way to solve a system like $(1)$ by hand. Maybe a combinatoric approach yields this formula without taking a detour through solving a system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to solve using the matrix. It's valid, but a bit unweildy. The solution is to use the recurrence relation 
$$
a_k = \frac 14 \left( a_{k-1} + a_{k+1} \right)
$$
with boundary conditions $a_0=0$, $a_n=1$.

Rewrite this as:
$$
a_{k+1} - 4a_k + a_{k-1} = 0
$$
This has solutions of the form $a_k = A \lambda^k$ where $\lambda$ is a root of the quadratic
$$
x^2 - 4x +1 = 0
$$
So 
$$
\lambda = {4 \pm \sqrt{12}\over 2} = 2 \pm \sqrt{3}
$$
And
$$
a_k = A(2 + \sqrt{3})^k + B(2 - \sqrt{3})^k
$$
for some $A, B$. Applying the boundary conditions sets these and gives the formula at the bottom of the post.

Comment: Isn't the boundary condition $a_0 = 0$?

Comment: “This has solutions of the form $a_k = A \lambda^k$ …” Why’s that? (The final formula looks to be of a different form (a *sum* of terms like $A \lambda^k$), to me.)

Comment: Oops - sorry about the typo. Fixed to read $a_0=0$. Thanks @Economist.

Comment: Why $a_k = A\lambda^k$. Any finite difference equation has solutions of this form. If $\lambda$ satisfies a polynomial $p$ then $A\lambda^k$ is a solution to the difference equation with the same coefficients. Try it out and you'll see that you can always cancel powers of $\lambda$ to get to the polynomial. The reason for the sum is that, because the difference equation is $homogeneous$ (that means it sums to $0$), the sum of any two solutions is also a solution.

Comment: @ScottBurns Any finite diff. equation with constant coefficients, that is.

Comment: @The Vee. Yes, quite right.